# Private git server: git clone asks for git@host's password

Tags: git, ssh, ubuntu-21.04, git-server

I've setted up a `git` private server on my desktop pc (OS ubuntu 21.04), and I whant to be able to work on those repos with my laptop or my desktop pc

- Already created `git` user (`root`,`my_user`,`git`)

- `ssh-server` service on

- `ssh rsa keys` generated (laptop and desktop)

- `ssh/authorized_keys` configurated

- Able to access via `ssh` from my laptop

- Able to access via `ssh` from my desktop to my destkop with `my_user`

- Able to `git push` from my laptop

But I have problems trying to git clone those repos on my destop pc

```
$ git clone git@Desktop:/home/git/repo.git
git@Desktop's password:
```

Instead of asking my password it ask the pasword for git user

Comment: You're specifying `git@` in the clone URL.  If you want to use your own account, don't specify a user.

Comment: @StephenNewell that makes no sense because only git user have permissions on /home/git/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Make sure to add `id_rsa.pub` to `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`

---

I found out that I mistakenly add my `id_rsa.pub` from `my_user` to the wrong `.ssh/authorized_keys` file by running cat comand.

`/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
git@Desktop:~$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa L4p70p+k3Y=
```

`/home/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
my_user@Desktop:~$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa L4p70p+k3Y=
ssh-rsa MY_u53r+k3Y=
```

I just have to add the missing key and it worked like a charm

```
my_user@Desktop:~$ git clone git@Desktop:/home/git/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), 632 bytes | 632.00 KiB/s, done.
```