# Git Asking for Instance's Password (not my user pw) after setting up ssh key

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitlab

I've been having repeated problems setting up ssh authentication, specifically whenever I get to this step git will ask for my remote's password, but I have no idea what that is and there seems to be no mention of this issue on other posts (perhaps it gets overshadowed by "git keeps asking for *my* credentials questions"). I don't know why this prompt comes up, or what this password would be. Ideally with my ssh key I shouldn't have to enter any password when pushing to remote anyway.

my steps were:

- rsa keygen (save it to /root/.ssh)
- cat the file and save it to GitLab
- eval "$(ssh-agent)" to start the process
- ssh-add -k /root/.ssh/id_rsa, a little iffy on what this does, but I believe saves the credentials
- git push

Then it gives me the output:

```
The authenticity of host <host> can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is <key fingerprint>
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added <host> (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
<host>'s password: ???????
```

At this point I don't know the password, so I can't push. Does anyone have insight into why I'm being asked this?

Comment: Can you include the git command you're entering?
Could it be because of something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490265